# What is the interest rate on my US Savings Bonds?

Tags: united-states, interest-rate, savings-bonds

I have received US Savings Bonds as gifts throughout my life from my birth, to birthdays, to high school graduation. My understanding is that some EE Series US Savings Bonds have a fixed interest rate and others have a variable interest rate depending on when the bonds were issued. How can I determine whether my bonds have a fixed or variable interest rate. Furthermore, if the interest rate is variable, how can I determine what the current interest rate is?

Comment: Try this [link](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ebonds/res_e_bonds_eeratesandterms.htm) to the TreasuryDirect website.  Should be able to look up the bonds there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, some are fixed and some are variable. It 100% depends on the EE Bond issue date. For example:

"EE Bonds issued from May 1997 through April 2005 earn a variable rate of interest. Treasury determines the rate each May 1 and November 1 and applies that rate for six-month rate periods that start in the next six months."

Read this for complete list of issue dates and interest rates:
https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ebonds/res_e_bonds_eeratesandterms.htm

Also, you can look up the exact value of your bonds at anytime by putting their serial number in here:
http://www.treasurydirect.gov/BC/SBCPrice